# How to Parse a nullable DateTime during a LINQ group operation?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, group-by

I need to group some rows due to Year of nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`). This is my code:

```
group x by DateTime.Parse(x.MyDate).Year into g
```

but since it's nullable, I can't do it.

`TryParse` needs `out` to a variable, which I think is futile here since it needs to be processed inside the LINQ matching.

How would you achieve this? External function? Or is there a faster/smart way?

Comment: I hope you aren't trying to do a query to a SQL db with that LINQ expression, because it won't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you target with Linq, maybe you can use:

```
group x 
by string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MyDate) ? (int?)null : DateTime.Parse(x.MyDate).Year
into g
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
List<DateTime?> dateTimes = new List<DateTime?>
    {DateTime.Now, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)};
var query = from x in dateTimes group x by x into g where g.Key.HasValue select g.Key;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid TryParse if it is defenetly DateTime? field. Then your result code will look like

```
var testx = from x in lst
            group x by x.MyDate.HasValue?x.MyDate.Value.Year:0 into g
            select g;
```